# If $g(y)=3\int_0^yxf(x)dx+2\int_{\ln\frac1y}^{\ln y}x^3f(|x|)dx-3f(y),y\in(0,3)$ then $18-g(y)=?$ where f(x) is as given in the question.

Tags: calculus, integration, limits

If $$f(x)=\lim_{t\to0}\int_0^x\left(\frac{tx^2+x\left(\left(t+1\right)^{2t+2}-1\right)}{e^{-x}t}\right)dx$$
and:
$$g(y)=3\int_0^yxf(x)dx+2\int_{\ln\frac1y}^{\ln y}x^3f(|x|)dx-3f(y),y\in(0,3)$$
then minimum value of $18-g(y)$ is?

---

I tried:
$$f(x)=x^2e^x$$
then:
$$g(y)=3\int_0^yx^3e^xdx+2\int_{-\ln y}^{\ln y}\underbrace{x^5e^{|x|}}_{\text{odd function}}dx-3y^2e^y$$ 
So:
$$g(y)=3e^y(y^3-3y^2+6x-6)-3y^2e^y$$ 
How to solve further?

Comment: In $f$ you have $x$ as both a limit and the variable you integrate with respect to. Are you sure this is what you want? If so, it is regarded as confusing, and you should change one of them.

Comment: @slo no it's perfectly fine

Comment: Technically it is not wrong, but it $x$ is both a free and a bound variable which can lead to confusion.

Comment: @slo limit is taken wrt "t" and integration wrt "x".

Comment: I was not talking about the limit $\lim$, but about the upper limit of the integral. Anyway, assuming your $g$ is correct, a global minimum does not exists as $\lim\limits_{y\to\infty}g(y)=-\infty$.

Comment: I've tried to make the title more specific. Also upvoted to counter the downvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually $$g(y)=3\int_0^yx^3e^xdx+2\int_{-\ln y}^{\ln y}x^3f(|x|)dx-3y^2e^y\\=3 e^y y^3-12 e^y y^2+18 e^y y-18 e^y+18\\g'(y)=3 e^y y (y^2-y-2)$$
$g'(y)=0$ at $y=-1,0,2$; also $g(-1)=18-51/e,g(0)=0,g(2)=18-6e^2,$